# photo gallery with possibility of selecting picture

Tags: android, photo-gallery

I'm going to develop an activity that shows a very simple photo gallery where photo files are taken from a given directory. The activity should allow the user to select a set of pictures and returns a vector of string representing the filenames of the selected picture.

Any advice? I do not wand to develop it from scratch and then discovering that there is a ready-to-use component that already does the job.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732508/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery

Comment: also check this out https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick it may be help ful